# Window management tools for Multiple monitor

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, multiple-monitors

i'm working on home and office using laptop. Always use dual monitor. Office monitor resolution is 1440x900, home monitor resolution is 1280x1024. I'm using Windows XP. My problem is when change location, remanage window position. For example: When i'm going to home and turn on computer and starting programs, on the dual monitor software window was overflowed.

How to easy manage window?

Is there any software?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AutoSizer](http://www.southbaypc.com/AutoSizer/) to keep your windows at a specific size. It's not the perfect solution, but I'm not aware of any other way. From the website:

> AutoSizer automatically resizes
>   programs for you, keeping them at a
>   specific size or keeping them
>   maximized. One popular use is to keep
>   Internet Explorer maximized when you
>   go on the web. It works with most
>   software programs, and supports
>   maximizing to specific monitors on
>   multi-monitor computers. Use the handy
>   Always On Top system tray menu to
>   quickly position specific programs
>   above all others.

If that doesn't work you could also try out [Sizer](http://www.brianapps.net/sizer.html). It allows you to resize a window to one of a few predefined resolutions.

To save your icon positions, you can use [DesktopOK](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/DesktopOK) . From [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5276016/desktopok-saves-your-desktop-icon-positions):

> Tiny application DesktopOK saves and
>   restores your desktop icon
>   positions—so your perfect icon layout
>   won't get lost if your resolution
>   changes when hooking to another
>   monitor or playing a game.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at **[PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm)**, a powerful display and (multi)monitor utility which supports multiple profiles.

*PowerStrip is shareware, try before you buy.*